# Is there a function that hides/unhides text?

Tags: feature-request

Is there a function that hides/unhides text?

The spoiler function renders text invisible, but it would be more useful to have a hide functions that compacts details of a proof, so that one can give the outline and if someone wants details they can click on the unhide button.

Note: This has been asked on meta.stackoverflow here: [Is there a function that hides/unhides text?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90296/is-there-a-function-that-hides-unhides-text)

Comment: It would actually be great to have this feature *instead of* the spoiler feature, which looks ugly and distracting on all my browsers.

Comment: I recall Jeff saying he didn't think much of the spoiler feature either, but it was added by popular demand...

Comment: You might want to request this on meta.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: I posted a request.

Comment: Here's the [link to the request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90296/is-there-a-function-that-hides-unhides-text). Thanks, user9325.

Comment: I have voted to close as off-topic.

Comment: @Moron: Why? I think it's quite OK to have feature-requests on meta.math.sx. (Why else would that tag exist? And the request is clearly related to math.sx!)

Comment: @Hendrik: Because the request has already been made at meta.so and we don't expect any answers here. By voting to close, there is no implication that future requests should not be made here. It will still show up in the search results and we can edit the question itself to point to the meta.so thread.

Comment: @Moron: Ah, OK - thanks!