# A hide/show feature

Tags: feature-request

There is a question [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2151/is-there-a-function-that-hides-unhides-text) on math.meta.stackexchange requesting hide/show features for posts. The person was then asked to ask the [same question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90296/is-there-a-function-that-hides-unhides-text) on the meta.stackexchange, where their request was rebuked (for what I feel like are poor reasons).

Is there any update on this situation? Either an implementation of hide/show within the stackexchange framework or a workable alternative. I think that such hide/show functionality would be very useful to hide remarks from a longer post, where such remarks could disrupt the flow of the main conceptual thread of the answer. I have been using the spoiler functionality for this purpose but it is...[unwieldy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4652524/why-are-p-adic-numbers-ubiquitous-in-modern-number-theory/4653014#4653014).